# HTML Forms - when the text box value changes

Tags: html, forms, input

I'm trying to figure out how to call a method everytime a text box in a form's value changes.

For example,

Is there a parameter I can add that is called everytime the user types something new in the box? I know there is an "onchange" but that is only called once the user is done typing in that box.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using JavaScript along with your HTML? (Just wondering because the question was not tagged 'JavaScript')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to us is an onkeyup event.  Without a js library your code should look similar to this (syntax is unchecked):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function keyup(x)
{
  //code
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname"  onkeyup="keyup(this)">

</body>
</html>
```

You can also use onblur if you want to check it when the user changes focus from the text box.

For more detail:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Comment: how would I make it print what the user is typing under the text box? and that text would change as they type different things?

Comment: print where? you can grab the value in that function by using x.value and set it to where ever you need.  there are many different ways to do that :-)